# Jquery input text allow decimal and value between 0.00 and 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, range, decimal

Jquery input text allow decimal and value between 0.00 and 100

**HTML :**

```
<input name="score type="number" min="0.01" max="100" step="0.01">
```

is showing invalid when i enter "1111" but i want to validation after i click the submit button

```
<input type="text" name="score">
<input type="submit">
```

**Script:**

```
if($(this).val()<= 0.01 && ($(this).val() <=100)){ // allow 0.01 to 100 100
     return true;
}
```

i want to allow only decimal in the Field

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: and your answer is. use html5 and not javascript for that look @ Marijn's answer

Comment: input type="number" is not working properly when i change the value of that field

Comment: @Developer: and how are you changing the value of that field? What does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: Do you want the checking to be done when the user submits the information (on click of a button) or when the user types in the text ( on keypress ) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use HTML for this:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.01">
```

If you don't want to use HTML:

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  
  $("#form").submit(function(e) {

    var scoreVal = $("#score").val();
    
    if(parseInt(scoreVal) <= 0 || parseInt(scoreVal) > 100) {
      
      e.preventDefault();
      
      console.log("Wrong value was entered!");
    
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input id="score" type="text" name="score">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Martijn  `input type="number"` is not working properly when i change the value of that field. that is my i am trying to implement script for type="text" field

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, it will outline the box in Red (in FireFox at least) and prevent the submission while it is out of specification.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar what do you mean ? User cannot type in anything but a number in type="number' fields

Comment: @Logar: User can type number > 100

Comment: But there is no submit button in the example.  I believe chrome would prevent the default submission action if the number is outside the range.

Comment: @Milind: true, but it's possible to use the `:out-of-range` (or possibly the `:invalid`) pseudo-class to style the element based on the value being out-of-range or otherwise invalid.

Comment: @Martjin, i dont want to use type="number", update your answer with other solution

Comment: @Developer that does not work that way, the solution is valid, if it does not fit your needs, do wait for more solutions + explain why this doesn't fit your needs by editing the question

Comment: its allowing "11111" , i want to restrict user allow up to 100, not even 101

Comment: you can use jquery onblur() to validate input when user leaves the field.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Interesting. I wasn't aware of these selectors. Thanks :)

Comment: @Martijn the Script allowing 0. value should be greater than 0

Comment: @Developer: change `< 0` to `<= 0`

Comment: if that is the case when user enter '0.01' will come as invalid. we should allow 0.01-100

Answer (score 1):

@Martijn Bots solution seems fair to me, in case you want to do it otherwise,    then you can check specifically for 0.00 and then correct your logic to validate range >=0.01 to 100

```js
function validate()
{
   if ( jQuery("#mytext").val() == "0.00"
   || ( $("#mytext").val() >= 0.01 && $("#mytext").val() <=100)  
   )
      { 
     alert(true);
     }
    else {
      alert(false);
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mytext" type="text" name="score" onblur="return validate();">
```